# Order by on date stored as text in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, datetime, android-sqlite

I have seen many question on this but nothing worked for me.

I am saving Date as text in my SQLite db. I want to retrieve it using order by

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_historynew ORDER BY datetime(eventdate) ;
```

The result I am getting:

```
Id  : 35487
date: Thu Jun 25 06:30:00 IST 2015

Id  : 35488
date: Thu Jan 01 05:30:00 IST 1970

Id  : 35533
date: Sat Jun 27 11:00:00 IST 2015
```

Comment: Why store Date as text?

Comment: @Nabin Storing it as text should work fine right? Or saving as timestamp is only option?

Comment: There is no reason I guess to store it as text. Try using Date or TimeStamp rather

Comment: @Nabin SQLite docs say that we can save it in text.

Comment: You can but why to do?

Comment: yes, you can store in text for date and it should store as as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS")

Comment: @calvinfly Thanks! I was about to say that! And also it is  working now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @calvinfly told, below is a code snippet.
Had to convert it to ISO8601 String!

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

String format_date  = df.format(date);

...and store format_date in DB!